# Physical reason for Helium-hole?

Tags: atomic-physics, atmospheric-science, inert-gases

I just found a *"Helium-hole"* from [atmospheric data provided here](http://omniweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/vitmo/msis_vitmo.html).
I was actually looking for this, and the first search was immediately succesful, a hole was found from;
Time: $05.01.2002$, $05:00$ UTC
Place: 68 Latitude, 0 Longitude on $112-138$ km height,
It's is shown in the picture below. As the picture shows the derivate, thus below 1 the amount is decreasing. The absolute amount was $-25.7\%$ less at $122$ km height than the peak above at 139 km.
The absolute amounts were $3.294 \times 10^{-7}~g~cm^{-3}$ at $122$ km height and, $4.434 \times 10^{-7}~g~cm^{-3}$ at $139$ km height.

As Helium [is chemically unreactive under all normal conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium#Compounds). And the temperature was $245~K ... 629~K$, and pressure $6.7 \times 10^{-4}~Pa...4.7 \times 10^{-3}~Pa$, which I consider "normal", as this vacuum is merely a "[medium vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path)".

**Thus there must be some physical reason for this, which I am just not aware of?**

This question is related;
[Why In Thermosphere is He and O divided as measured?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240979/why-in-thermosphere-is-he-and-o-divided-as-measured)

[image: Helium hole]

Edit; It seems that the this is not actaully a hole. The picture below shows how the amount of Helium is actually constantly higher above $140~km$ height.

[image: Helium in Atmosphere 5.1.2009]